# Feign client and how to cast JSON-response to Application/Unencoded

Tags: java, spring, spring-cloud-feign

I have a post method which can produce two types of response.
The first one is with 200-OK status:

```
{"payment_uuid": "8f7f62e7-8ede-42d1-901c-68ae2651bc82"}
```

The second one is for an error:

```
["The user already has a subscription"]
```

I use FeignClient, my current type of a response is `ResponseEntity<T>`.
How can I check, is the body has a JSON type with a `payment_uuid` field or with a response description? Do I need to change response type of my method?

Answer (score 1):

I think you could implement an [error decoder](https://github.com/OpenFeign/feign/wiki/Custom-error-handling) and catch the thrown exception inside an `@ControllerAdvice`. This way, you could define your POJO (which has `payment_uuid` field) in `ResponseEntity<T>` without worrying about the error description, because it'll be handled by the error decoder.